# How to improve the speed of reading multiple csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dask

It's my first time creating a code for processing files with a lot of data, so I am kinda stuck here.

What I'm trying to do is to read a list of path, listing all of the csv files that need to be read, retrieve the HEAD and TAIL from each files and put it inside a list.

I have 621 csv files in total, with each files consisted of 5800 rows, and 251 columns
[image]
This is the data sample

```
[LOGGING],RD81DL96_1,3,4,5,2,,,,
LOG01,,,,,,,,,
DATETIME,INDEX,SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0]
TIME,INDEX,FF-1(１A) ,FF-1(１B) ,FF-1(１C) ,FF-1(２A),FF-2(１A) ,FF-2(１B) ,FF-2(１C),FF-2(２A)
47:29.6,1,172,0,139,1258,0,0,400,0
47:34.6,2,172,0,139,1258,0,0,400,0
47:39.6,3,172,0,139,1258,0,0,400,0
47:44.6,4,172,0,139,1263,0,0,400,0
47:49.6,5,172,0,139,1263,0,0,450,0
47:54.6,6,172,0,139,1263,0,0,450,0
```

The problem is, while it took about 13 seconds to read all the files (still kinda slow honestly)

But when I add a single line of append code, the process took a lot of times to finish, about 4 minutes.

**Below is the snipset of the code:**

```
# CsvList: [File Path, Change Date, File size, File Name]
for x, file in enumerate(CsvList):
     timeColumn = ['TIME']
     df = dd.read_csv(file[0], sep =',', skiprows = 3, encoding= 'CP932', engine='python', usecols=timeColumn)

     # The process became long when this code is added
     startEndList.append(list(df.head(1)) + list(df.tail(1)))
```

Why that happened? I'm using dask.dataframe

Comment: Would you post a sample of your file-structure ?

Comment: You need to become parallel. Try PySpark. Distribute your files across several HDD.

Comment: `startEndList` is a list or a dataframe?

Comment: @Corralien it is a list, because i don't really understand how to process the data later using dataframe

Comment: If you use the same code with pandas (`pd.read_csv`), I think it should be faster

Comment: @Corralien I used pandas before, before using dask. It took way longer than 13 seconds

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov What makes PySpark better than dask? Isn't dask also use parallel computing

Comment: One issue is that you read the whole file, while you only need the first and last line; you don't even use/need the header row, since you turn the relevant rows into lists, which thus ignores the headers.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Do you really want to get the first row and the last row (or it is just an example)?

Comment: @Corralien Yes, for this process I only need the Start time, and End time, thus only the head and tail. But in the other function I need to retrieve almost all the data, thus same problem will definitely occured later

Comment: @9769953 I thought without reading the whole file, there's no way to know which data is the tail? | I am using windows 10

Comment: Using a file pointer starting at the end and moving to the previous newline can get the last line. Which is the "1-tail" of a CSV. Similarly for the 4th line (since you skip the header and first few rows).

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you use bash/zsh or similar (through git-bash or WSL) and not something else, I don't know a quick tool. Otherwise, you could use the `head` and `tail` tools to grab those lines for each file, put them in a set of tmp files, and read those 2-line CSV files into Python. It is likely much faster (`head` and `tail` would are optimised for line access like that).

Comment: So I'm thinking whether it'll be faster in Python with manual file access and moving the file pointer around, reading just those lines, and after reading converting the lines into records.

Comment: For a quick experiment, you could test how long it takes for all files in total, to manually iterate through each line (without doing anything). E.g., `for filename in filelist: with open(...) as fp: for line in fp: pass`.

Comment: You're free to use any tool you know of to parallel reading from an HDD. The difference between `dask` and `Spark` I rarely heard of dask managing PB's of data in industrial settings. Though I must admit you're not alone asking this question.

Comment: By the way, how often does this happen? There are 621 files, and it takes 4 minutes total. Is that a one-off, or are you doing this continuously (in which case, the number of files seems strangely particular).

Comment: @9769953 I'll try the experiment now, is your open() function use csv.reader() function? Or still using dask?
Not a one-off, that 4 minutes is the average from numbers of trials. There's even a problem where I need to reread all the CSV files, including new files every 5 minutes. So 4 minutes of my app freezing is definitely a no no

Comment: No, I would have mentioned csv.reader() if it used it. That's only the last step, once you've read the individual lines.

Comment: Corralien's answer gets close to my suggestion, except that using `split(',')` may be incorrect with CSV files (see my comment). That is where csv.reader would come in, *after* having read the lines, using a `io.StringIO` object.

Comment: @9769953. Same idea! Great minds think alike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first approach using only Python as starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

def read_first_and_last_lines(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        # skip first 4 rows (headers)
        [next(fp) for _ in range(4)]
        # first line
        first_line = fp.readline()
        # start at -2x length of first line from the end of file
        fp.seek(-2 * len(first_line), 2)
        # last line
        last_line = fp.readlines()[-1]
        return first_line + last_line
        
data = []
for filename in pathlib.Path('data').glob('*.csv'):
    data.append(read_first_and_last_lines(filename))

buf = io.BytesIO()
buf.writelines(data)
buf.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buf, header=None, encoding='CP932')
```

Comment: You could grab the length of the fourth line (`first_line`), double it, and assume that is a safe assumption for at least the length of the last line.

Comment: Note that simply using `.split(',')` will not account for quoted fields, and should not be used when reading a CSV.

Comment: @9769953. I updated my answer according your comment. I used `io.String` to create a buffer of 2 lines then `pd.read_csv` to process the buffer. I think it is safe now. What do you think about?

Comment: @Corralien is using seek() will make the function same row dependent? If for example there's another csv file with different number of rows. It will break?

Comment: Heh; that follows pretty much my suggestions I've made in the comments to the question.

Comment: @MarioAriyanto. I go to the end of file, so the number of lines doesn't matter.

Comment: I would move the `read_csv` file outside of all the looping. Concatenate all the individual lines (so not a list of list, but a single list), *then* treat that as a single `io.StringIO` unit and use `pd.read_csv()`. At the very end, reformat the resulting dataframe into a list of 2-element list as necessary. The reason is that I think it may save a bit of time (only one use of `pd.read_csv()`, and I think it's clearer as well.

Comment: @MarioAriyanto `seek()` works per individual file. For seek, there are no rows, and it certainly doesn't care about other files.

Comment: @9769953 My image of seek() is wrong then, thank you for the clarification
I will try this solution, pretty excited right now

Comment: I guess it you'd like to go a step further: read everything as binary, and only do the decoding in `pd.read_csv()`; just treat everything before that (each list element) as a binary string. (This assumes the suggestion from my previous comment.)

Comment: @9769953. I updated my answer. I moved to `io.BytesIO`

Comment: Hm, I think you now return the first and last line concatenated to each other. You probably want `return [first_line, last_line]`, and in the outer loop, `data.extend(....)`. Of course, concatenating CSV files to each other will stay a CSV file, *except* for a missing comma in between (which provides another solution, depending on what the OP wants as output).

Comment: I don't strip `\n` so it's safe to use `first_line + last_line`. My idea is `data.extend` is slow

Comment: Ah, right: I always forget where Python does and does not strip the newline. (I'm now guessing it actually never strips the newline.)

Comment: @CorralienSo does this 'df = pd.read_csv(buf, header=None, encoding='CP932')' convert the list, back into dataframe? does this mean data[] cannot be used as it is?

Comment: @MarioAriyanto. No since `data` is a bytes string (raw text). Pandas try to guess the type of each column (convert a string to numeric if possible). The overhead to use `pd.read_csv` is not a big deal. You have only 621x2 rows now.

Comment: To convert to a list of list, use: `df.to_numpy().tolist()`

Comment: Can you update your post with the 4th and the last row of this file, please?

Comment: @Corralien Ignore the last comment about the error, it was my own mistake. I forgot to delete the dummy csv when running the program. XD

Comment: @Corralien It run without error, but df returned with  [1242 rows x 251 columns]

Comment: Yes 621 files x 2 rows x 251 columns. If you want to convert it to a list of list, use `df.to_numpy().tolist()`.

Comment: This code works. It tooks 5 seconds to process all 621 files in average.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, your code isn't really leveraging Dask's parallelizing capabilities because:

- `df.head` and `df.tail` calls will trigger a "compute" (i.e., convert your Dask DataFrame into a pandas DataFrame -- which is what we try to minimize in lazy evaluations with Dask), and
- the for-loop is running sequentially because you're creating Dask DataFrames and converting them to pandas DataFrames, all inside the loop.

So, your current example is similar to just using pandas within the for-loop, but with the added Dask-to-pandas-conversion overhead.

Since you need to work on each of your files, I'd suggest checking out [Dask Delayed](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed.html), which might be more elegant+ueful here. The following (pseudo-code) will parallelize the pandas operation on each of your files:

```py
import dask
import pandas as pd

for file in list_of_files:
    df = dask.delayed(pd.read_csv)(file)
    result.append(df.head(1) + df.tail(1))

dask.compute(*result)
```

The output of `dask.visualize(*result)` when I used 4 csv-files confirms parallelism:

[image]

If you really want to use Dask DataFrame here, you may try to:

- read all files into a single Dask DataFrame,
- make sure each Dask "partition" corresponds to one file,
- use Dask Dataframe `apply` to get the `head` and `tail` values and append them to a new list
- call compute on the new list

Comment: I see, now I understand. much appreciated