# Reading multiple csv files with spark is very slow?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to read multiple csv files from a specific folder. However, even with only two files in the folder, the reading runs infinitely. Follow the code

```
df = spark.read.csv("data/*.csv",sep =';', header = True)
df.printSchema()
```

When I run the same code for one file only, it only takes a few seconds.

```
df = spark.read.csv("data/file1.csv",sep =';', header = True)
df.printSchema()
```

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is. The two files have the exact same header and are similar in size.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to improve the speed of reading multiple csv files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391114/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-reading-multiple-csv-files-in-python)

Comment: Can you try reading using folder path: `df = spark.read.csv("data", sep=';', header=True)`

Comment: Have you tried reading the files by specifying the schema beforehand? You can use the `.read.schema(yourSchema)` and set the `.option("inferSchema", "false")`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I know how to read using dask, but I'm learning pyspark and wanted to read large datasets using the method I described. I don't understand why it keeps running infinitely, because the files in the folder aren't even that big and I can read them individually.